# Android autoLink="phone" programmatically?

Tags: android, android-intent

I need to have button same feature as with in xml autoLink="phone".

Currently I'm able to make the phone call when pressing the button, but I can't open the phonenumber for the dialer.

So I don't want the button to call right away. I want the user have the number on dialer and be able to modify the number before dialing.

How can I make this kind of feature using Java?

Answer (score 3):

Ah ok.

I needed to change `ACTION_CALL` to `ACTION_DIAL`

Answer (score 0):

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvphoneValue"
        android:layout_width="112dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:autoLink="phone"
        android:maxEms="15"
        android:text="number you want to call" />
```